# How to check progress of sql-sync that hangs up?

Tags: drush

I run:

```
drush sql-sync @mysite.es.remote @mysite.es.local
```

then I hit `Yes` to continue then command completely hangs up for ever. Meanwhile I checked phpMyAdmin and it seems that it's synced my local database with remote but it's still missing some tables.

Is there any way how to check progress of sql-sync?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Run with `--verbose` or `--debug` to see more and lots of output, respectively, or run with `--simulate` to see only the commands that Drush *would* run.

Another helpful thing to do with sql-sync is to run `drush @mysite.es.remote sql-conf` and `drush @mysite.es.local sql-conf` - this will print out the database records `sql-sync` will use for the two sites.  In your case, since you are getting to the `y/n` prompt, this part is probably working.